# Applying a function to a single R data.frame column: lapply and apply not working - looking for R equivalent to Python's DataFrame.apply(...)

Tags: python, r, dataframe, apply, lapply

Python coder here, but I have some shapefiles I need to process in R with data attached which I need to convert from its current format to regular datetimes by applying a simple function to the column with the datetime data. This is straightforward to do in Python, but I keep getting strange errors when using apply and lapply in R (see below for details). It's likely the answer is relatively straightforward since I'm much less familiar with R than Python, so any help is much appreciated.

## R version

```r
# df is an R data.frame with 54 columns. The only one relevant for this
# question is df["ISSUE_DATE"], which is currently a list of 13-digit 
# integers. I need to convert it to a regular datetime.

df$ISSUE_DATE[0:5]
[1] 20011001000000 20030228000000 19990910000000 20131108000000
[5] 19970930000000

fix_date = function(x){
  string_x = toString(x)
  datestr = substr(string_x, 0, 8)
  result = as.Date(datestr, "%Y%m%d")
  return(result)
}

df$fixed_dates = lapply(df$ISSUE_DATE, fix_date)

# This returns a column with the same value - fix_date(df$ISSUE_DATE[1])
# - in every row:
df$fixed_dates[0:5]
[1] "2001-10-01" "2001-10-01" "2001-10-01" "2001-10-01"
[5] "2001-10-01"

# What I want instead is the result of fix_date applied to each value in 
# df$ISSUE_DATE as the values of df$fixed_dates:
df$fixed_dates[0:5]
[1] "2001-10-01" "2003-02-28" "1999-09-10" "2013-11-08"
[5] "1997-09-30"
```

## What this would look like in Python:

```py
df["fixed_dates"] = df["ISSUE_DATE"].apply(fix_date)
```

Answer (score 1):

Distinguish between the following:

- `df["colname"]` is a data frame with one column, namely "colname"
- `df$colname` is a *vector* holding the contents of the "colname" data frame column

So you want to do either

```
df$FIXED_DATE <- fix_date(df$ISSUE_DATE)
```

*or*

```
df$FIXED_DATE <- lapply(df["ISSUE_DATE"], fix_date)
```

The former would be the idiomatic way to do it.

Comment: In his "R version" section you'll notice the OP actually did try to apply using `df$ISSUE_DATE`, so I don't think he's confused about how vectors work.

Comment: @SweepingsDemon OP is comparing this to Pandas `apply`, which applies across columns by default. The fact that `lapply`, when given a vector, also happens to produce a result is just a coincidence.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately neither of those suggestions work. The first one returns `[1] "2001-10-01" NA           NA           NA          
[5] NA...` (the first date followed by all null values) and the second one returns `[1] "2001-10-01" "2001-10-01" "2001-10-01" "2001-10-01" 
[5] "2001-10-01"` (the first date repeated into every value in the dataframe column). What I'm looking for is to convert every integer to in the current `df["ISSUE_DATE"]` column into a date in the format I've specified.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to write a function and do that to convert string to dates. Below is the code you are looking for. BTW, `ymd` is from `lubridate`.

```
Input
df <- c("20011001000000","20030228000000", "19990910000000", "20131108000000", "19970930000000")
df <- ymd(as.POSIXct(df,format="%Y%m%d%H%M%OS"))

Output:
"2001-10-01" "2003-02-28" "1999-09-10" "2013-11-08" "1997-09-30"
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This worked (even though I'm starting with integers rather than strings).